# CSharp program crashes when using external int in proc

Tags: c#

I'm writing a Unity program in C# and the following code makes it crash:

```
public class WmGetMessages
{
    public delegate void GetMsgProc(int code, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet=System.Runtime.InteropServices.CharSet.Auto, BestFitMapping=false)]
    [ResourceExposure(ResourceScope.Machine)]
    public static extern IntPtr GetModuleHandle(string modName);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern IntPtr SetWindowsHookEx(int hookType, GetMsgProc hookProc, IntPtr instancePtr, uint threadID);

    private static Process _process;
    private static ProcessModule _module;
    private static IntPtr _handle;

    public static void Install()
    {
        _process = Process.GetCurrentProcess();
        _module = _process.MainModule;
        _handle = GetModuleHandle(_module.ModuleName);

        InstallHook(14);
    }

    public static void InstallHook(int i)
    {
        Debug.Log("Installing: " + i);
        GetMsgProc proc = (code, wParam, lParam) => {
            Debug.Log("SetWindowsHookEx; i: "+i+", code: "+code+", wParam: "+wParam+", lParam: "+lParam);
        };
        IntPtr hook = SetWindowsHookEx( i, proc, _handle, 0);
    }
}
```

It crashes because I'm using the `int i` in `Debug.Log()` which is inside the `GetMsgProc proc`, when I remove `"+i+"` from the log it works.

I'd like to know why, does this have something to do with GC? What I can do to prevent it from crashing.

Comment: Did you get any specific message with that "crash"?

Comment: No, Unity just quits and no error is given. I'm not sure where or how to catch the exception. (try-catch doesn't help..)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You instantiate the delegate `proc` and then pass it to `SetWindowsHookEx`. However, nothing after that point references `proc`, and so the GC will collect it.

Native code then tries to invoke that delegate, with bad results.

You need to keep a reference to `proc` for as long as it might be called.

Since you're creating an anonymous delegate which captures variables from its surrounding scope (most notably `i`), in practice this means:

1. Don't use an anonymous delegate - create a single non-capturing delegate which is stored in a static field on `WmGetMessages`, and is used for all calls to `SetWindowsHookEx`
2. If you do need to create a new anonymous delegate per call to `InstallHook`:

   1. Return a value to your caller, which the caller must store in a field until the hook is uninstalled
   2. Keep some sort of static list of delegates inside the `WmGetMessages` class (and remove delegates from it when you uninstall the corresponding hook)

---

Let's dig into why removing `"+i+"` specifically makes it work.

If you don't reference `i` in the delegate, the delegate is non-capturing: it doesn't capture anything from its surrounding scope. The compiler will create a single `GetMsgProc` and then cache it:

```
[Serializable]
[CompilerGenerated]
private sealed class <>c
{
    public static readonly <>c <>9 = new <>c();

    public static GetMsgProc <>9__7_0;

    internal void <InstallHook>b__7_0(int code, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
    {
        object[] obj = new object[6];
        obj[0] = "SetWindowsHookEx; code: ";
        obj[1] = code;
        obj[2] = ", wParam: ";
        obj[3] = wParam.ToString();
        obj[4] = ", lParam: ";
        obj[5] = lParam.ToString();
        Debug.WriteLine(string.Concat(obj));
    }
}

public static void InstallHook(int i)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("Installing: " + i);
    GetMsgProc hookProc = <>c.<>9__7_0 ?? (<>c.<>9__7_0 = new GetMsgProc(<>c.<>9.<InstallHook>b__7_0));
    IntPtr intPtr = SetWindowsHookEx(i, hookProc, _handle, 0u);
}
```

[SharpLab](https://sharplab.io/#v2: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)

See how the `GetMsgProc` instance is cached in `<>c.<>9__7_0`. This means that even though you're (incorrectly) not keeping the delegate instance alive yourself, it just so happens that a compiler optimization is keeping it alive for you.

However if you do reference `i`, the compiler then needs to generate a new delegate instance every time you call `InstallHook` (because each instance needs to capture a different value for `i`):

```
[CompilerGenerated]
private sealed class <>c__DisplayClass7_0
{
    public int i;

    internal void <InstallHook>b__0(int code, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
    {
        object[] obj = new object[8];
        obj[0] = "SetWindowsHookEx; i: ";
        obj[1] = i;
        obj[2] = ", code: ";
        obj[3] = code;
        obj[4] = ", wParam: ";
        obj[5] = wParam.ToString();
        obj[6] = ", lParam: ";
        obj[7] = lParam.ToString();
        Debug.WriteLine(string.Concat(obj));
    }
}

public static void InstallHook(int i)
{
    <>c__DisplayClass7_0 <>c__DisplayClass7_ = new <>c__DisplayClass7_0();
    <>c__DisplayClass7_.i = i;
    Debug.WriteLine("Installing: " + <>c__DisplayClass7_.i);
    GetMsgProc hookProc = new GetMsgProc(<>c__DisplayClass7_.<InstallHook>b__0);
    IntPtr intPtr = SetWindowsHookEx(<>c__DisplayClass7_.i, hookProc, _handle, 0u);
}
```

[SharpLab](https://sharplab.io/#v2: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)

See how it now generates a new `GetMsgProc` every time you call `InstallHook`.

Comment: Thanks for the clear and detailed explanation! I bet I will be using SharpLab more often, nice tool. I got it working now by creating a `List<GetMsgProc>` which stores all references of the created procs. I clear it when the program gets terminated. Too bad this bad code isn't failing at compile time. Must be a reason for that though.

Comment: @TimBaas When everything's in the managed .NET world, the compiler and runtime can work together to make sure that everything's safe. However the minute you start doing unsafe things -- p/invoke, `unsafe`, etc -- you're on your own.

Comment: @TimBaas Also bear in mind that `List<T>` isn't thread-safe. Static methods are generally assumed to be thread-safe in C#. You probably want to use a thread-safe collection (e.g. `ConcurrentBag`)

Comment: @TimBaas There's no point in clearing that list when the application terminates - it's being destroyed anyway. If your house is being demolished, there's no point in tidying the kitchen.